# Prob. 6, Sec. 4.2 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: Continuity of a subadditive functional at zero implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a real normed space, and let $p \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a functional such that 
$$ p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X$$
and such that 
$$p(\theta) = 0, \ \mbox{ where $\theta$ denotes the zero vector in $X$.} $$
Suppose that $p$ is continuous at $\theta$.

Then how to show that $p$ is continuous at any point $v$ of $X$?

Since $p$ is continuous at $\theta$, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that, for all $x \in X$ with $\Vert x - \theta \Vert < \delta$, we have $$\vert p(x) - p(\theta) \vert = \vert p(x) \vert < \epsilon.$$

What next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that

The subadditivity of $p$ shows that
\begin{equation}
p(x) = p(x - y + y) \leq p(x-y) + p(y)
\end{equation}
so that $p(x)-p(y) \leq p(x-y)$. This also shows that $p(y) - p(x) \leq p(y-x)$. Hence
\begin{equation}
-p(y-x)\leq p(x) - p(y) \leq p(x - y).
\end{equation}

Let $x\in X$ be any point. Showing continuity of $p$ at $x$ means that given any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that $|p(x)-p(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$. So, let $\epsilon>0$. Then by continuity of $p$ at $\theta$ we know that there exist $\delta>0$ such that $|p(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $\|z\|<\delta$. Now, whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$ then note that $p(x-y)<\epsilon$ and similarly $-\epsilon <-p(y-x)$ and hence
\begin{align}
-\epsilon <-p(y-x)\leq p(x)-p(y)\leq p(x-y) <\epsilon & & \Rightarrow & & |p(x)-p(y)|<\epsilon. 
\end{align}

Comment: Hello, @Urban PENDU? Thank you for your answer. But how do you conclude that $p(x-y) = p(y-x)$?

Comment: regarding the question in my last comment. Since $0 = p(\theta) = p(x-x) = p(\ x + (-x) \ )  \leq p(x) + p(-x)$, we have $-p(x) \leq p(-x)$; so $-p(-x) \leq p(\ -(-x) \ ) = p(x)$. What next?

Comment: sorry i took $p$ to be a seminorm....I will edit the argument....

Comment: please do. Are you doing an MPhil in mathematics? Which phase are you in ---- research or coursework? Are you from Punjab in India?

Comment: made an edit...please have a look and if there is any mistake let me know...I think the argument is fine now....I am doing M.Sc Mathematics

Comment: thanks. What has your B.Sc. in mathematics education been like? I mean which material have you been taught from in your analysis, topology, and functional analysis courses?

Comment: in B.Sc we covered rudin's baby book in analysis and topology was covered from Munkres.....functional is a course in masters programme...here is a link that will give the complete course structure of the Bachelor's programme......http://www.isibang.ac.in/~statmath/courses/brochure.pdf

Comment: how much of Rudin and Munkres did you cover back then? And, how thoroughly did you cover these books? can you please share with me your notes from any of the courses you've taken?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't posses the notes of the courses I took....I have given to my juniors.... but you can see the link in my last comment. It specifies the topics that were covered in the courses explicitly....And I will also try to get a hold on the notes and try to give them to you...but I can not make a promise but I will try....

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$|p(x)-p(y)|= p(x)-p(y)$ ou $p(y)-p(x)$, but as shown above we have
$$ 
p(x)-p(y)\leq p(x-y)\leq |p(x-y)|
$$
and
$$
p(y)-p(x)\leq p(y-x)\leq |p(y-x)|.
$$
On the other hand, by continuity of $p$ at $\theta$ we know that if $|| x-y||=||y-x||<\delta$, then 
$|p(x-y)|<\epsilon$ and too $|p(y-x)|<\epsilon$, and hence,
$$|p(x)-p(y)|<\epsilon,$$
which proves that $p$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

First, a hint. Try considering the difference $p(x)-p(y)$. Can you show this gets small as $x\rightarrow y$? (Remember the standard trick of adding $0$ in a suitable form.)

Comment: That's just what I'm struggling to achieve, @Stromael. So can you please elabotate on your hint?